# mysql 404 error

Tags: mysql

have the following code:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {

$reqwidth = $_POST['reqwidth'];
$reqside = $_POST['reqside'];
$reqrad = $_POST['reqrad'];
$sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO tirelist (width, sidewall, radial) VALUES  ('$reqwidth','$reqside', '$reqrad')";

if (!mysqli_query($dbcon, $sqlinsert)) {
die('error inserting new record');
 }

$newrecord = "1 record added to database";

}

?>

<html>
<head>
<title>Request Tire Size</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Request Tire Size</h1>

<form method="post" action="insert-data.php">
<input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="true" />
<fieldset>
<legend>Request Tire</legend>
 <label>Tire Width: <input type="text" name="reqwidth" /></label>
<label>Tire Sidewall: <input type="text" name="reqside" /></label>
<label>Tire Radial: <input type="text" name="reqrad" /></label>
 </fieldset>
  <br />
 <input type="submit" value="Send Order Request" />
  </form>
```

when i click send order request, I get a 404 error.

i noticed the page is called ~http://localhost/index.php?p=test2~, but when i click it redirects me to ~http://localhost/insert-data.php~

been trying for hours, wondering what i could do to fix it

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<form method="post" action="insert-data.php">
```

to have index.php?p=test2 instead.

Answer (score 0):

In your form, you reference `insert-data.php`. Does that exist?

If you're trying to submit the form to the same file, you can try to use this:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead. form method="post" action="/insert-data.php"